# Query SQL Cannot work with Controller Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the SQL Query

```
SELECT sum(statement.amount)
FROM statement, lender
WHERE statement.type = 01
AND lender.id = statement.lender_id
AND statement.stat = 888
AND lender.user_id = users.id
```

And this is my code in controller

```
$count_totaldeposit = DB::table('statement')->join('lender','lender.id', '=', 'statement.lender_id')
                                            ->where('lender.user_id',$userId)
                                            ->where('type',01)
                                            ->where('statement.stat',888)->sum('statement.amount');
```

I don't know where the issue is, 
can anybody help me with the code?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What have you tried yourself solving it? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Comment: The Sum is not working, display nothing in the front end.

Comment: Try to use `->groupBy()` on  that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just need to add ("") inside 01.

like this :

```
->where('type',"01")
```